# How to install oauth2 on IPython-Notebook

Tags: python, pip, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to import oauth2 on IPython-Notebook. When I do:

```
import oauth2
```

Errors happens:

```
ImportError: No module named 'oauth2'
```

For a regular installation, I should install the module first by:

```
pip install python-oauth2
```

But I am not sure how to install this module on IPython platform.

Finally, I guess the general version of this question is: how to import a module on Ipython?

---

**Solution:**

Thanks to Monkpit, the mistake that I made is attempting to do pip install on IPython instead of a terminal. After I corrected this and run

```
python -m pip install oauth2
```

It works.

Comment: IPython isn't a platform, it's just an interface to a normal Python platform. So long as the `pip` command is running on the same Python as IPython uses, it should install modules in the right place. If you're not sure, you can use `path/to/python -m pip install ...` to run pip with a specific Python executable.

Comment: Have you actually tried `pip install python-oauth2` yet? From your question's wording it sounds like you may not have tried this? What happens if you do?

Comment: @Monkpit, it shows "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Comment: @ThomasK, that sounds reasonable. I guess the 1st step is to install pip.

Comment: @enaJ you need to be running any `pip` commands from your terminal, not from IPython itself. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Before you try this answer, read this!

If you have already run `pip install python-oauth2` from your terminal - **not from IPython!** and you still cannot `import oauth2` in your IPython session, read on.

#### To install a package to an unknown IPython kernel

Check which python executable you're running in IPython/Jupyter by running this code from inside IPython:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

And you'll get some result like: `/usr/bin/python` or `C:\\Python\\python.exe`. In my example, I'll be using `/usr/bin/python`, but you should use whatever your result was.

Take that result and, **from your terminal** run:

`/usr/bin/python -m pip install python-oauth2`

If that command was successful, `import oauth2` should work from your IPython session. If it wasn't successful and you get a `SyntaxError`, then you need to make sure `pip` is installed correctly. See the [`pip` documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) for details, and run any `python` commands with the python path from your IPython notebook's `sys.executable`.